# Import XML or JSON data into Excel using URL from a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml, api, json, microsoft-excel-365

I have an API call to make from my Excel spreadsheet that will have various parameters depending on the data entered in the spreadsheet.

I have formatted the URL properly and have it in a cell that is named `ApiUrl` however when I try to set up a data source in Excel, it seems to always require me to provide the URL in the setup wizard rather than referencing data in my spreadsheet (such as this pre-formatted URL).

I am certain there must be a way to do this...but I have not been able to find it.

I am using the latest Office365.

My URL can be formatted to return XML or JSON data if one format or the other gives me the capabilities I am looking for.  It is also OK if I need to set up each parameter as a reference to a cell rather than the URL string being precomposed.

Once I get the data into my workbook, I can take it from there...I just need help getting data from a precomposed URL string.  Thanks!

The URL is something like:

https://developer.nrel.gov/api/pvwatts/v6.xml?api_key=MY-API-KEY-HERE&address=&system_capacity=12.5&azimuth=&tilt=&array_type=1&module_type=1&losses=10.5

This will return XML (or with a slight modification, JSON) data formatted as described here:
https://developer.nrel.gov/docs/solar/pvwatts/v6/

I am only trying to get the "ac_monthly" array...and will then be inserting those 12 values into individual cells in my sheet.

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of your cells' URLs?

Comment: I don't think you can do this using the wizard. Your will need to edit the query itself. Please provide sufficient information so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I added the API url and reference link.  I can probably figure out how to parse the relevant parts once I get them...I just can't make the initial handshake through Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your queries in Power Query.

Here is a sample code to use content from named range ("apiURL") as api URL:

```
let
    apiAddress = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="apiURL"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiAddress)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

Step by step:

1. enter your link in a cell
2. assign custom name to the cell
3. open power query
4. create a new blank query: home - new source - blank query
   [image]
5. open advanced editor
   [image]
6. copy the code from above (adjust range name if needed)
7. close power query (select "keep changes")

[image]

Comment: This looks promising...but can you add the steps to get there?  I have not used the Power Query Editor before.  When I go to it, the whole lower window is greyed out, as are many items in the toolbar.  I assume I need to first create a new source, but that sends me through the wizard.  Thanks!

Comment: @techtheatre: added step by step instructions

Comment: This works AWESOME.  Thank you so much.  If there was a "buy me a beer" button on this site, one woudl be headed your way for sure.  This is perfect.